# How do I show the tab bar in Firefox Elm?

Tags: firefox, windows-8

How can I show the tab bar in Modern UI Firefox (Elm, 19.0a1 2012-11-01) as in the following screenshot?

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmGGp.jpg)

I assume some gesture would work, but I don't have a touchscreen.

I can currently switch tabs using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but no tab bar!

When I add a new tab with the plus button on the top right, I see tab previews briefly but they disappear as soon as the page loads:

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tNT0.png)

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJWvN.png)

**How can I get the tab bar** (either from the first or last screenshot) **to show on demand and let me select a tab?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply right click **twice**! The first right click will show the address bar and orange settings/zoom/whatever bar down the bottom; the second will hide the orange bar and show the tabs!

From there, to get the first screenshot's view, click the three dots on the top right to `Always show tabs`!

<sup>Note that this is <s>beta</s><s>alpha</s>pre-alpha software, so parts may potentially break every update.</sup>